# Name for someone who writes content to generate website traffic

Tags: terminology, programming

> What is the job title or name for people who creates content for a social media website to drive traffic.

For example, a new social media site wants viewers so they have a small group of people who are content experts write posts and answer other posts.  They may or may not be paid.

***Options I've got so far:***

```
Volunteers, moderators, early adopters, betas...
```

<sub>For the record, I don't like these options...</sub>

Comment: I would use *copy-writers*, but that's a publishing term. You might want to call them *contributors*?

Comment: *Content generator*, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the phrase almost invariably used is "content creator" (or worse, "content generator").  There was a comic floating around a few years back that depicted some marketing wienie referring to Shakespeare as "a premium content-creator".

Answer (score 1):

I think content writers is the best suited.
For instance:

> Need experienced content writers for a website.

Answer (score 1):

But you drive traffic in many ways.

At a high level a `content manager`.

A `moderator` drives traffic.

`UX` drives traffic.

Fake positive reviews drive traffic but I don't know what you call that.

SEO drives traffic - `SEO expert`?

Answer (score 0):

Content Writer or Web Content Writer is a generally used title or name for people who create content for a website or ablog to drive traffic.

There is no specific term or title for those who write content for social media websites. They are generally called content writers only. If someoneone writes a blog then one can be called as a blogger.